# What tools do people use for including research?

Tags: discussion, questions

It's been a couple of months since I joined this community and needless to say while posting the questions we have to include the research we have done to prevent it from being flagged or worse being removed. I see people using some google tools to search for the origin and different aspects of a word. I am not aware of such tools and usually post anything which springs to my mind and call it my research(pun intended). I would like you to kindly let me know which tools exist and when do we use them. I suspect that many of the confusion would be cleared if I use these tools and would save the site from getting filled with "bad" questions from my side, regardless of the number. Till now, I have heard about Ngram, the phrase finder and I am yet to explore them. I would like you to give me a recommended list of places to search before putting them on EL&U. Thank you.